# Heroku: relation does not exist

Tags: python, heroku, flask, peewee

I am using Python, Flask, and the Peewee ORM.  My DATABASE_URL is set correctly.

I have tested the functionality on a local server and it works correctly. When I deploy to Heroku, it errors out on the table that Peewee creates in the `if name == main` section of my app.

The error is:

```
ProgrammingError: relation "connection" does not exist (connection 
is the name of my model/would-be table).
```

UPDATE: I fixed the problem by creating the table in the views.py file under the specific route. Is this necessary? I would prefer a cleaner way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used Heroku, but I'm guessing that Heroku is importing your app in some way that bypasses the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block which is only run when this module is run directly. You should try moving the logic from that `if` block into a [`before_first_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.Flask.before_first_request) handler so that it will still be run, but only once (per worker / app instance)

```python
@app.before_first_request
def initialize():
    app.logger.info("Creating the tables we need")
    ...
```